# Play an audioplayer not from the begining

Tags: java, processing, minim

i'm using minim library to play/pause/stop/ ... an audioplayer, and i was wondering if there s a way to play it not from the beginning but for example 10s after.
I explain why i want to do that i use sox with my program to create lowpass/highpass/... filters on my audioplayer but this way im only able to replay the sound from the beginning. So maybe combining the duration() function and millis() i can build a semblance of something continuous. 
Thanks for your help if you have any advice to help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/audioplayer_method_play.html) there is an overload for `play()` available, which looks like this:

```
void play(int millis)

Parameters
    millis — int: how many milliseconds from the beginning of the file to begin playback from
```